# how can i track or trace hotlinker ip address?

Tags: php

is there any way to find out ip address of a hotlinker?

Comment: I think you need a hostname rather than IP. `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Comment: Please elaborate in much more detail what your situation is

Comment: Look in your server logs - assuming you turned logging on and log the remote host.

Comment: I have so many images in my “images” directory I can prevented  hotlink to my image by using   “.htaccess”  ; I don’t wanna block hot linkers ; I I wanna trace their ip address how can I do the same?

Comment: Change all of you images to goatse and then wait and see who complains.

Comment: I wanna one more thing I wanna by pass “Real Hide IP”(proxy server) and get the real ip address of the victim

Comment: You said victim IP address? Whom you call a victim? A hotlinker's site visitor? it's `REMOTE_ADDR`, silly. but it's more likely you have not a faintest idea what are you doing, lol. Because proxy servers has nothing to do with hotlinking at all

Comment: Ok let me explain ; I wanna build a new web sight lik safeprofile.com They provide traking ip address uainga image link(hot linked image) how can I do the same?

Comment: @sudeep what does the web site you link to have to do with hotlinking? I don't understand.

Comment: they provide a link like this <div style="position: absolute; top: 2; right: 2"> <a href="http://marketsages.com/in.php?id=265320" target="_blank"><img src="http://marketsages.com/safe/265320.jpg" border="0" /></a></div>    and they track the ip address in our admin page   here is the web:http://www.safeprofile.com pls check the same out!!!!

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is not possible without downloading the whole world wide web. The closest you can get is looking at `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` when someone accesses your page. `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` might tell you the URL that provides a link to your page. From that URL you can extract the host part and use DNS to get the IP address.

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` can be manipulated by the client. This means

- if it's not there it does not mean that the user did not follow a link,
- if it's there, it does not mean that the user followed a link.

Chances are, the value is what is expected of it most of the time. But you should not build something critical around this assumption.

Comment: I wanna one more thing I wanna by pass “Real Hide IP”(proxy server) and get the real ip address of the victim

Comment: All that blab about referer unreliability has nothing to do with hotlinking, dude

Comment: Ok let me explain ; I wanna build a new web sight lik http://www.safeprofile.com/
They provide traking ip address uainga image link(hot linked image) how can I do the same?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: No it does not. But when I suggest a solution that does not *exactly* fit the problem, I'd like to explain *where it does* fit the problem and *where it does not* fit the problem. That way, the reader can decide whether the suggested solution is good enough for him.

Comment: you still do not understand what are you talking about. 1. using referer is the only possible solution, so, there is nothing to choose from. 2. again, all that unreliability stuff has nothing to do with hotlinking. You either do not understand the question or do not understand how these things works.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: I know that the referer is a practical solution. I do not know whether that solution is good enough. I mentioned some of the shortcomings of the suggested solution to enable the reader to decide whether that solution is good enough for him.

Comment: that's the problem. all answers here a theoretical ones, and authors have no idea if it ever works

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: No, they are practical. A theoretically correct answer would be: "download the whole World Wide Web". But that is not practical (if you are not Google).

Comment: you again din't get the point. `I do not know whether that solution is good enough`. So, you signed that you know nothing. Period.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: I did get it. But there is a gap between what the reader wants and what the reader asks. I can only answer what the reader asks. I try to anticipate what the reader wants. But ultimately, he has to decide.

Comment: they provide a link like this <div style="position: absolute; top: 2; right: 2"> <a href="marketsages.com/in.php?id=265320"; target="_blank"><img src="marketsages.com/safe/265320.jpg"; border="0" /></a></div> and they track the ip address in our admin page here is the web:safeprofile.com pls check the same out!!!! and pls get me a solution